# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-4.0.0) - APIs not getting deployed to the 2nd node in a clustered setup

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm using the latest API Manager(wso2am-4.0.0) and I am trying to implement the clustering of 2 nodes in 2 separate servers. I am trying to sync the APIs according to the below documentation, setting up deployment.toml files in both nodes accordingly.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/synchronizing-artifacts-in-a-gateway-cluster/#inbuilt-artifact-synchronization

Currently, the APIs appear in both the nodes once deployed from the 1st node. But, when I try to access the API in the 2nd node(by requesting using Postman), it results in a 404 resource not being found. Interestingly, if I restart the 2nd node, the API starts working in the 2nd node as well.

Any solution for this is most welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In built sync option is available by default in APIM v4. You don't need to do anything additionally. Please follow this if you haven't done so far - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/single-node/configuring-an-active-active-deployment/

Comment: @Pubci Sure. Will try this.

Comment: @Pubci I followed the documentation link. Still the APIs respond 404 not found from one of the nodes until it is restarted. Any idea on how to sync the APIs in real-time without restarting?

Comment: When you create an API in one of the nodes, it sends an event to the other node. Can you compare your configs as in https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/advanced/am-pattern-1/templates/am/instance-1/wso2am-pattern-1-am-conf.yaml and https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/advanced/am-pattern-1/templates/am/instance-2/wso2am-pattern-1-am-conf.yaml

Comment: @Pubci I compared both the deployment configurations and they seem to be fine. Could you kindly specify which configuration exactly makes the nodes sync?

Comment: @Pubci It finally worked. I'll post the configuration which worked. There seems to be an error in the documentation's step no.08. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below configuration worked for the APIs to sync between the nodes.

Node 1

```
[apim.throttling]
event_duplicate_url = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:5673"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://127.0.0.1:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<Node2_IP>:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<Node2_IP>:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"
```

Node 2

```
[apim.throttling]
event_duplicate_url = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:5672"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://127.0.0.1:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<Node1_IP>:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<Node1_IP>:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"
```

PS: In the documentation, the 2nd configuration's IP is mentioned with the localhost IP which needs to be corrected as above.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/single-node/configuring-an-active-active-deployment/

Step number 8.